# Trying to find all the cities that there is not a direct flight to from a city (PostgreSQL)

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm trying to write a query that determines which cities I can't fly to directly from a city, say London. Given the schema:

cities:

```
| c_id |   city_name    |
```

flights:

```
| f_id | departure_city_id | destination_city_id |
```

currently my query returns the opposite, i.e. it returns the cities for which there is a direct flight from London

```
SELECT c2.city_name as "City"
FROM flights AS f
JOIN cities AS c2 ON f.destination_city_id != c2.c_id
JOIN cities AS c ON c.c_id = c.c_id
WHERE c.city_name = 'London'
AND c.c_id != c2.c_id
AND f.departure_city_id = c.c_id;
```

I would have thought it would be easy to change it to get what I want.
I thought changing the third line to

```
JOIN cities AS c2 ON f.destination_city_id = c2.c_id
```

Would have done the trick but it didn't. Any help?

Answer (score 1):

> cities I can't fly to *directly* from a city, say London.

Meaning one *can* fly there, just not directly from London. So `JOIN` (not `LEFT JOIN`) `city` to `flight` via `destination_city_id`:

```
SELECT DISTINCT c.city_name
FROM   cities c
JOIN   flights f ON f.destination_city_id = c.c_id
JOIN   cities c2 ON c2.c_id = f.departure_city_id
WHERE  c2.city_name <> 'London';
```

Then I only have to exclude flights originating from London, apply `DISTINCT` to get unique city names and we are done.

A more sophisticated interpretation of this question would be:
*"Cities you can fly to from London, just not directly"*
But since this looks like basic homework I don't assume they'd expect a *recursive query* from you.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like:

```
SELECT * 
FROM cities c
WHERE c.c_id NOT IN
(SELECT f.destination_city_id
 FROM flights f
 JOIN cities c2 ON f.departure_city_id = c.c_id
 WHERE c2.city_name = 'London')
```